# Reduce Mobile Phone reception for app testing

Tags: testing, mobile, streaming

I know this is not directly programming related, but is there a way to purposely limit the signal strength on a testing mobile device to determine how your app performs under weak signal conditions?

I have an app that streams video and audio to a server, and need to test how it performs in low signal areas.. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a software like network link conditioner on OSX and netlimiter on windows, they have options for bandwidth limiting and even packet loss and presets for different typical situations plus the ability to create some yourself, you can just create a wifi network on your machine and connect to it from the device you want to test

please not that iOS has network link conditioner built-in (you can find it under the developer menu in settings), while android may have something on a rooted device (never tried anything though)

Answer (score 1):

One realistic way to do it is put it in a weak Faraday cage. You can make one or buy a bag or other pre-manufactured cage that protects against radio transmissions. As long as it's not *too* strong, it should weaken but not completely block the signal.

Answer (score 0):

If run run your app in a simulator, many have options for emulating poor signal conditions.

Answer (score 0):

There is at least one open source project whose aim is to simulate different network conditions for exactly the type of testing you are describing:

- https://github.com/facebook/augmented-traffic-control

This can work in a cellular network but in this would most likely require your own base stations etc. This is possible via other open source projects (e.g. http://openbsc.osmocom.org/trac/), but is likely not necessary as you can probably simulate the same affect with the WiFi test set up.